# Google Custom Document Classifier scores unknown document types as successful

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

New to Google Document AI. Trying to create a custom processor for classification of different document types manually in Google cloud console/Document AI (i.e. not via API)
After a bit of training, known document types are correctly labled to a reasonable degree of confidence. My problem occurs when I load an unknown document type into the processor. The unknown document is scored with 100% confidence as an (random?) existing document type.

I trained the processor with two different document types ("type1" and "type2"), both a set of pdf files.Samples of type1 are very uniform as are the samples of type2.

I trained the processor with the minimal required set of each document type (10 for training and 2 for testing each).
When verifying the processor, it managed to classify new documents of type1 and type2. My problem occurs when I load an unknown document type ("typeX") into the processor. It then labels the typeX as classified as one of the two proper ones with 100% confidence.

I tried to round the problem by introducing a third classification label (unknown) and trained it on a random set of document types (excluding type1 and typ2). This resulted in unknown document types being classified as unknown - which is correct. However, each type1 and type2 test document was classified as both type1, type2 and typeX with 100% confidence in this model version.

Finally I tried to use HILT to teach the processor which document types were unknown, but it never triggerd due to the high confidence score.
Is there any sensible way to handle typeX/unknown document types in Google CDC?

Grateful for any tips that can push me forward!